# how can I set filter menu config in pluto_grid as antd Table

Tags: flutter, antd, pluto-grid

[image]
https://ant.design/components/table#table
[image]
how can I achieved this in [pluto_grid](https://github.com/bosskmk/pluto_grid)

the first pic is what I did in web with antd

I reimplemented this table in flutter with pluto_grid as below, however don't know how to get this check filter menu on table header